# Implementing Nesetril and Poljak's clique detection algorithm

Tags: java, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I want to write Java code to implement the clique detection algorithm by Nesetril and Poljak described at http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106381/CommentatMathUnivCarol_026-1985-2_22.pdf However i can't seem to understand how the auxiliary graph H is to be created and how it can be used to detect a clique. For instance, the paper suggests that to detect a clique of size 3l in a graph of size n, we construct an auxiliary graph H of size n^l. For the detection of a clique of size 6 in a graph G of size 8 for example, then the size of H would be 64 (i.e. 8^2) and then checking for the presence of a triangle in H which would indicate the presence of a clique of size 6 in G. Further down, while describing how to construct H, they stated that the vertex set of H should be a subset of the vertices of G, and that the size of this subset is l. This is the first conflict. The second conflict is in the construction of the edge set. What is meant by Y'?

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about the algorithm in that paper and not about the concrete programming.

Comment: I would think that understanding the algorithm in the paper would be the first step towards the actual programming. If you can explain it directly through concrete programming, that will be appreciated as well.

Comment: This site is probably not the right place for explanation of the algorithm itself. Maybe math.stackexchange.com is a better fit for questions regarding graph theory.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you.

Comment: @Eiko that algorithm is looking at `O` and is a known problem in computer science: chygoz2 I would suggest searching on [computer science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=subgraph) and seeing if any of the Q&As there help

Comment: @JGreenwell thank you for your suggestion. I'll look for answers there also.